# How do you create a route in MVC to handle multiple parameters but not show them in the url

Tags: model-view-controller, url-routing

I have user records with a unique identifier, first and last name.

I'd like to display the url as **www.server.com/Profile/JoeBloggs**, but pass a parameter of the unique identifier to the controller action to look up the user.

I'm able to create urls with the format **www.server.com/Profile/XXX-XXXX/JoeBloggs**, however don't want to show the unique id in the url - does anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Form (using HtmlHelper) and an HTTP Post with the parameters instead of an Url link and an HTTP Get with query string parameters.